# Why Angular Material input password shows two eyes for visibility and how can I display just one?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Always into my Angular 15 migration ....

Today, my problem is with an input password that shows two eyes the fist time we input something in the field.

The code is the following in the HTML file :

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
  <input matInput [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'" name="password">
  <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="togglePasswordVisibility()">
    {{showPassword?'visibility_off':'visibility'}}
  </mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

And something like this in the corresponding Typescript component :

```
...
  public showPassword: boolean = false;
  public togglePasswordVisibility(): void {
    this.showPassword = !this.showPassword;
  }
...
```

And the result is :

[image]

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

I found a solution by removing the input password toggle with this CSS :

```
input[type=password]::-ms-reveal,
input[type=password]::-ms-clear
{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: That looks suspiciously like the Windows ([Fluent UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui)) eye which makes me think it's being added by your browser (are you using Edge?) because your input is of `type="password"`. Have you checked other browsers?

Comment: I am at work, we are using edge and no way to use another one. I will try at home. By the way, I found a solution with the CSS added in the main post

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by removing the input password toggle with this CSS :

```
input[type=password]::-ms-reveal,
input[type=password]::-ms-clear
{
  display: none;
}
```